# How to make custom shape in jetcompose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a shape like below image in jetpack compose

**Expected Output**

[image: preview]

I tried using box with clip and rounded corner shape, but not working as expected output.

```
 @Composable
    fun SemiOvalShape() {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight(.4f)
                    .fillMaxSize(1.0f)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(bottomStart = 180.dp, bottomEnd = 180.dp))
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
                    .background(color = Color.Blue)
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use ```Canvas``` for makings custom shapes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Canvas** to achieve these outputs. You can play around the value to make more changes.

**Preview**

[image: preview]

**Code**

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Stack03() {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(400.dp)) {
        drawCircle(
            color = Color(0xFFACBCCB),
            radius = 800f,
            center = Offset(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 5.0f)
        )
        drawCircle(
            color = Color(0xFF0B305E),
            radius = 775f,
            center = Offset(size.width / 2.0f, size.height / 5.0f)
        )
    }
}
```